# My html and javascript code is not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have written a html and javascript files.
Here is my code
HTML:
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Bitter|Ubuntu+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>

      <li>New value: <span class="my-new"></span></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script src="event.js"></script>
</html>
```

and  here is my javascript code

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {

  document.querySelector('.my-new').textContent = e.newValue;
  
});
```

I write something on another page and want to display it on another page(the code of this page is shown here). Everything is fine, the code is working on Chrome. However, when I open it on safari, it does not display.

Javascript is enabled. I have no idea what is the problem. Please, help

Comment: What version of Safari are you testing this on?

Comment: Safari version is 13.1.1

Answer (score -1):

Wich safari are you on? could be that your safari is old and you need to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.my-new')
```

or better give it a id and use:

```
document.getElementById()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: This seems unlikely, Safari has supported `querySelector` for 12 years! Browser support for it is **better** than `getElementsByClassName`! (And it is `document`, not `Document`).

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the feedback edited, but not sure what else could be the problem. Maybe you can check by doing a console log if the event is triggered in Safari?